# Symfony2, log exception in specific file

Tags: php, symfony, exception

I'm working on an API with Symfony and FosRestBundle.

In my ApiController, I want to log all exception in a specific file: api.log

Here an example of my code:

```
   public function getUserAction($param){
        if(is_int($param)){
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Account')->findOneById($param);
        }
        else{
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ProjectBundle:Account')->findOneByUsername($param);
        }

        if(!is_object($user)){
            return "User Not Found";
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

Where i need to catch and log the exeption ? In `if(!is_object($user)){` or when i retrieve `$user` ? And How can i save and log the exeption in my file api.log ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion should add a kernel.exception event listener, which writes the exception in the api.log file

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html